# Form not submitting in IE 7 only

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, internet-explorer-7

I have a form that submits great in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE 9 & 8. But IE 7 doesn't submit the form at all, I've looked at other threads but I can't find an answer to why it isn't working for me. You can see the full page here http://go.nelson.com/myNelsonMigration.html

My input code is already:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">
```

The full form code is below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>myNelson Upgrade Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://go.nelson.com/rs/nelsoneducation/images/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://go.nelson.com/rs/nelsoneducation/images/jquery_validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://go.nelson.com/rs/nelsoneducation/images/SHA1.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://go.nelson.com/rs/nelsoneducation/images/bootstrap.min.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://go.nelson.com/rs/nelsoneducation/images/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://go.nelson.com/rs/nelsoneducation/images/style3.css" media="all">

<!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCheckBoxValue(id){
        if($("#"+id+":checked").length > 0){
            return "1";
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }
    }
    function getGrades()
    {
        var grades = "";
        $("#grades input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
                grades += $(this).parent().text()+",";
        });

        return grades.substring(0, grades.length-1).substring(1);
    }

    function getInterests()
    {
        var interests = "";
        $("#interests input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
                interests += $(this).parent().text()+",";
        });
        return interests.substring(0, interests.length-1).substring(1);
    }

    function getNewsletters()
    {
        var newsletters = "";
        $("#newsletters input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
                newsletters += $(this).parent().text()+",";
        });
        return newsletters.substring(0, newsletters.length-1).substring(1).replace(/ - View Sample/g, '');
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#province').val("");


        $("#form-marketo").validate({
            rules: {
                email: {email: true, required: true},
                namefirst: "required",
                namelast:  "required",
                position: "required",
                                    City: "required",
                province: "required",
                schoolboard: "required",
                                    school: "required",

            },
            submitHandler: function(){
            var lead_data = {
                Email: $("#email").val(),
                Title: $("#position").val(),
                State: $("#province").val(),
                                    City: $("#city").val(),
                SchoolBoard: $("#school-board").val(),  
                                    School: $("#school").val(),
                Preference_Center_Interests : getInterests(),
                Preference_Center_Newsletters: getNewsletters()
            };
            lead_data["FirstName"] = $("#name-first").val();
            lead_data["LastName"] = $("#name-last").val();



            mktoMunchkinFunction('associateLead', lead_data, SHA1("NelsonEdu2013"+$("#email").val()));
            //sub form submit redirect
            setTimeout("location.href='http://go.nelson.com/myNelsonUpgrade_Confirm.html';",3000);
            return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    Label.error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <a href="http://nelson.com/" class="header-logo"></a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <form action="" method="post" id="form-marketo">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <div class="step1">
                            <h2 style="line-height: 40px; color: #3B4953; size: 40px; text-align: center;">Fill in your information</h2>

                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input-block-level">

                            <label for="name-first">First name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="namefirst" id="name-first" class="input-block-level">

                            <label for="name-last">Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="namelast" id="name-last" class="input-block-level">

                            <label for="position">Position</label>
                            <select name="position" id="position" class="input-block-level">
                                <option value="">Select a Position</option>
                                <option value="Administrative Staff">Administrative Staff</option>
                                <option value="Consultant">Consultant</option>
                                <option value="Department head">Department head</option>
                                <option value="Director">Director</option>
                                <option value="Homeschooler">Homeschooler</option>
                                <option value="Lead Teacher">Lead Teacher</option>
                                <option value="Librarian">Librarian</option>
                                <option value="Principal">Principal</option>
                                <option value="School Purchasing Agent">School Purchasing Agent</option>
                                <option value="Student Teacher">Student Teacher</option>
                                <option value="Supply Teacher">Supply Teacher</option>
                                <option value="Superintendent">Superintendent</option>
                                <option value="Teacher">Teacher</option>
                                <option value="Teaching Assistant">Teaching Assistant</option>
                                <option value="Technology Specialist">Technology Specialist</option>
                                <option value="Vice principal">Vice principal</option>
                                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                            </select>

                            <label for="city">City</label>
                            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="input-block-level">

                            <label for="province">Province</label>
                            <select name="province" id="province" class="input-block-level">
                                <option value="">Select a Province</option>
                                <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                                <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                                <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                                <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                                <option value="NL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                                <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                                                                    <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                                <option value="NT">Northwest Territories</option>
                                <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                                <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                                <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
                                <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                                <option value="YT">Yukon</option>
                            </select>

                            <label for="school-board">School Board</label>
                            <select name="schoolboard" id="school-board" class="input-block-level">
                                <option value="">Select a School Board</option>
                            </select>

                            <label for="school">School</label>
                            <select name="school" id="school" class="input-block-level">
                                <option value="">Select a School</option>
                            </select>

            <p align="center" style="margin-top:1em; font-size:25px">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">
                </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        </div>


                            </div>






            </form>
        </div> <!-- /span12 -->
    </div> <!-- /row -->
</div>

<script src="http://go.nelson.com/rs/nelsoneducation/images/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://go.nelson.com/rs/nelsoneducation/images/dropdown1.js"></script>
<script src="http://go.nelson.com/rs/nelsoneducation/images/scrollToElement.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        var width = $(window).width(); // Get window width
        if (width <= 480) {
            $('.btn').addClass('btn-small');
        }

        // Radio/Checkbox label tap fix for iOS devices
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
            $('label[for]').click(function () {
                var el = $(this).attr('for');
                if ($('#' + el + '[type=radio], #' + el + '[type=checkbox]').attr('selected', !$('#' + el).attr('selected'))) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    $('#' + el)[0].focus();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `school: "required",` The trailing comma here might cause an issue

Comment: @scrappedcola That fixed it! Thanks so much from a humble non-developer :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`school: "required",` The trailing comma here might cause an issue

Comment: The OP said this fixed the issue... wouldn't that be considered an 'answer to the question'?